# Positivity of a series of functions involving double poles constrained by certain inequalities

Tags: calculus, derivatives

This is a calculation I need for my statistics project

**Big edit: simplify the function $f(x)$ a lot.**

Define for $f(x)$, $x\geq 0$,
$$
f(x):=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k^2\lambda_k^2x}{(1+x\lambda_k)^2} - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{b_k^2\beta_k}{(1+x\beta_k)^3}
$$
where $a_k\in \mathbb R$, $b_k\in\mathbb R$, $\lambda_k>0$, $\beta_k> 0$, and
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k^2\leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k^2<\infty\,\text{ and }\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k^2 \lambda_k\leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k^2 \beta_k<\infty.
$$
Additional assumption: we may think each $\beta_k$ is very large. You may take it as large as you want.

I am trying to prove that $f(x)$ has following graph. That is, prove that there exists $x_0>0$ such that $f(x_0)=0$, and for all $x<x_0$, $f(x)<0$, and for all $x>x_0$, $f(x)>0$.
[image]

---

This question has already been solved in this [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1636745/the-uniqueness-of-roots-of-quartic-function) We only need to take $\beta:=\min(\beta_i)$ and the function $(1+\beta x)^3f(x)$ is increasing.

Comment: I don't understand one thing; it seems to me that you call by the same name $f(x)$ a series of functions and $f(x)$ which is a particular $f_k(x)$

Comment: @JeanMarie Sorry for confusion. Edit!

Comment: Why not express $$f_k(\alpha):=\frac{\alpha\lambda_{k}^2}{(1+\alpha \lambda_{k})^3}-\frac{\beta_{k}}{(1+\alpha \beta_{k})^3}$$ It doesn't solve your problem, but it does make the calculations a little cleaner.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thx. Edit!

Comment: Are you sure you've posed enough conditions for it to be negative at $\alpha = 0$? Seems that if it's positive at 0 you're out of luck.

Comment: @MichaelChirico I add one more assumption $\sum a_k=1$ and $\sum b_k\beta_k>0$ to guarantee that $f(0)=0$. Thank you pointing out!

Comment: Hmm, that was the easy way out and now you've contradicted your goal -- first, you've plopped the answer right in your lap by finding a 0 of $f$; second, your graph seems to imply you want $f <0$ for $\alpha < \alpha^{*}$ (as in your base case, where $f(0) = -\beta$

Comment: @MichaelChirico  where is the contradiction?

Comment: You said you wanted $\alpha_0 > 0$ and also $f(\alpha) < 0 \, \, \, \, \forall \alpha < \alpha_0$, but now you've got $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: @MichaelChirico ha? $f(0)=-\sum b_k\beta_k<0$ right?

Comment: Re-read your comment above...

Comment: @MichaelChirico Sorry it I confused myself... If $\alpha=0$, then the first term and second term kills each other since $\sum a_k=1$, and hence $f(0)=-\sum b_k\beta_k<0$ as desired...

Comment: @MichaelChirico I see, I forgot a '$-$' in my privious comment...

Answer (score 1):

@Tankonetoone: On an experimental basis, I am convinced that the assertion is NOT TRUE, under hypothesis $\sum \lambda_k \leq \sum \beta_k < \infty $. BUT, it LOOKS TRUE (for all the cases I have tried...), if one assumes the inequality $\sum \beta_k \leq \sum \lambda_k < \infty $.

Indeed, I have taken at first $\lambda_k=\dfrac{1}{k^3}$ and $\beta_k=\dfrac{1}{k^2}$ in order that the initial summation inequalities are fulfilled.

I have made (see Matlab program below) a summation  with $1000$ (and even much more) terms, for various values of $\alpha$ in the range $(0,10000)$: the curve of function $f$, though increasing, remains desperately below the abscissas' axis.
I have then tried different other cases, e.g., $\lambda_k = \dfrac{1}{k^{2}}$ and $\beta_k = \dfrac{1}{k^{3/2}}$ all with the same negative result.

Reversing the roles of the $\lambda_k$s and $\beta_k$s, i.e., assuming $\sum \lambda_k \geq \sum \beta_k$, I obtained curves like the one displayed by the author in the different cases I have tried.

Could you confirm?

---

MATLAB PROGRAM:

> clear all;close all;n=1000;
>      L1=10;L2=500;step=0.5;
>      range=L1:step:L2;
>      Inv=1./(1:n);
>      B=Inv.^2;L=Inv.^3;% not convenient
>      %B=Inv.^3;L=Inv.^2;% convenient
>      f=@(a)(sum((a*(L.^2)./((1+a*L).^3)-B./((1+a*B).^3))));
>      S=[];
>       for a=range;
>          S=[S,f(a)];
>       end; 
>       plot(range,S)

Comment: Sorry for my late reply! Interesting, since for the case that $k=1$, we can explicitly prove that $\lambda<4\beta$ is a necessary and sufficient condition.

Comment: I double check my formula. You are absolutely right. So I changed it a bit by writing done the very original equation. Please have a look!

Comment: Can you give a little hint at the probabilistic/statistical context of your big initial formula. It might suggest a track...

Comment: It's really long... basically you can think $u=a_k u_k$ where $u_k$ is an orthonormal basis of $L^2$ and $-\Delta u_k=\lambda u_k$.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to modify your previous title.