# The uniqueness of roots of Quartic function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Define 
$$
f(x):=(1+ax)^3x-a(1+x)^3.
$$
Would it be possible to prove that the function $f$ has only one positive real root provided that $a>0$? (There might be another root $x_0<0$, but I only concern the case that $x>0$).

Also, I plot it out in wolframalpha. It looks to me that $a$ has to bigger than some positive number. For example, $a=0.2$ wouldn't work.

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps the discriminant can be of use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, this is only true for $a>1/4$.

Here is a proof:

Your polynomial can be factorized as $(ax^2 - 1)(a^2x^2 + (3a-1)x + a)$.

The first factor gives a positive root, and a negative one.

So one has to concentrate on the second factor, let us call it $Q_a(x)$, that should have no real roots.

The discriminant of $Q_a(x)$ can be factored into $\Delta=(1-4a)(a+1)^2$.

Thus, $\Delta < 0$ (which means "no real roots") is equivalent to $1-4a<0$ i.e., $a>1/4$.

If $0<a<1/4$, the two real roots of $Q_a(x)$ are $>0$ because their sum $(1-3a)/a^2$ and their product $1/a$ are themselves $>0$.